# Postgresql - How to access to multiple layer json array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have table with structure (key, value). [value] column have sample data here:

```
{
"id": "example@gmail.com",
"cates": [
    {
        "cateId": "car",
        "packages": [
            {
                "packageId": "package-i",
                "isInsurance": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I want to select all key where value have [packageId] = 'package-i' and I trying:

```
SELECT t.key, json_array_elements(json_array_elements(t.value->'cates')->'packages') AS cates FROM t
```

to create all pair (key, package) then check packageId = 'package-i'. But performance is not good.

Do you have any ideas for my case?

Comment: The question is pretty vague.  Can you change the schema?  Create new tables?